# how to understand class parameter in scala

Tags: scala

How do you understand the class parameter in scala. Will the compiler add implicit field to the class for the class parameter.
Like

```
    class Rational(n:Int, d:Int){
        val num = n
        val den = d
        override def toString = n + "/" + d
    }
```

do we have 4 fields in class Rational (n, d, num, den)? If not, how can we access n and d in method toString. What's the mechanism behind this?

Comment: @Downvoter, why -1? Please, explain.

Comment: If you change your class declaration to `class Rational(val num:Int, val den:Int){ ...` then you don't need the separate `val` declarations within the body of the class because corresponding final fields for `num` and `den` are automatically created.

Comment: @Daowen, Yeah, I know this, just try to figure out the logic behind this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` and `d` will become `private` fields unless they are only used in the constructor, in which case they're optimised away. `num` and `den` will also be `private` fields, but they get `public` accessors as well.

Try this:

```
class Test(a: String) {
  println(a)
}
```

Then compile and run `javap -private Test`, which shows all classes and members of the class:

```
public class Test extends java.lang.Object{
    public Test(java.lang.String);
}
```

Then try with a method that uses that parameter:

```
class Test(a: String) {
  println(a)
  def printa { println(a) }
}

public class Test extends java.lang.Object{
    private final java.lang.String a;        // <- private field
    public void printa();
    public Test(java.lang.String);
}
```